# real time streaming vs push rest api

Tags: powerbi

Can someone tell me the difference between real time streaming vs  push data with power bi rest api. If I push data with rest api to a dataset the reports refreshes itself. Then I can have a program that pushes data with rest api every n seconds. What advantages does real time streaming API have?